# Call a code behind function from div/tables in aspx

Tags: asp.net, frames

Currently I am using frames in my webpage and I am calling a code behind function using src attribute. Now I wanted to remove frames from my webpage. Can I achieve the same behavior of method call when I replace frames with DIV or Table?

```
<FRAME name="nav" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" src="<%=fnGetMenuSource()%>" frameBorder="0" 
                noResize scrolling="no">
```

Comment: No, you can't embed an external resource in a webpage using pure HTML the same way you can with Frames. Please explain exactly what it is you are trying to do i.e. why were you frames and why are you now trying to get rid of them?

Comment: We designed our website using asp.net and it will work perfectly only with IE. Now we are doing code changes for achieving cross browser compatibility. Hence we are removing frames. During page onload fnGetMenuSource will load menus in the webpage.

Comment: load menus from where? An external source? Sorry but unless you provide a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to do in your question I'm afraid it's unanswerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can. With div, you can do like this:

```
<div id="divNav" name="nav"><%=fnGetMenuSource()%></div>
```

And in the code you might write the `fnGetMenuSource()` like this:

```
protected string fnGetMenuSource()
{
    return "<p style=\"color:red\">Hello World!</p>";
    // Or whatever you need
}
```

And the output for the code above:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Afzalulh!! Is it possible to call a htm page from another location using div tags?. For example I have the following code <frame SRC="../files/Logout.htm" NAME="head" NORESIZE SCROLLING="NO" FRAMEBORDER="0"
    MARGINHEIGHT="0" MARGINWIDTH="0" width="100%">

Comment: You have to use iFrame instead of div.